# Auto start slave

Tags: mysql, replication

Every time the MySQL service is restarted, the master-slave replication is stopped.  Is there a way to set the master-slave replication to start automatically after the service is restarted.

I am running MySQL on Windows.

Thank you,

Answer (score 6):

I order to auto start slave, enable this line in the my.cnf (or my.ini) file.

```
skip-slave-start = FALSE
```

Comment: Or just remove the line altogether.